# Web Application: Getting SynchronizationContext.Cuurent null in async call back .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, .net-4.0

I am trying to create an async call in a web page. On a click button event I have the following code:

```
  public delegate DataSet AuthorizeDelegate(SynchronizationContext uiContext);

    protected void lnkBindHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmartCabinetSession.ReportDataSet = null;
        SynchronizationContext uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        AuthorizeDelegate ad = new AuthorizeDelegate(GetHistoryDataSet);
        IAsyncResult ar = ad.BeginInvoke(uiContext,
                                         new AsyncCallback(AuthorizationComplete),
                                         null); 


    }

    public void AuthorizationComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Retrieve the delegate that corresponds to the asynchronous method 
        AuthorizeDelegate ad = (AuthorizeDelegate)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;

        // Get the result of the asynchronous method
        DataSet authorizationCode = ad.EndInvoke(ar);
    }

   private DataSet GetHistoryDataSet(SynchronizationContext uiContext)
    {
       uiContext.Post(UpdateUI, someobject);

        return historyDS;
    }

    private void UpdateUI(object aaa)
    {
       //access ui and session from here
    }
```

However, the line:
 uiContext.Post(UpdateUI, someobject);
throws exception as uiContext.current is null.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use **async/await**?

Comment: There is no UI in ASP.NET. UI is in browser, not on server side.